# Save error: Illegal assignment from String to Integer

Tags: apex, string, compile-error

I need a string value transformed to a integer so that I can use it in a number field.

```
Integer leadSize=(Integer.valueOf(email.plaintextbody.split('Base: ').size()) > 1) ? email.plaintextbody.split('Base: ').get(1).split('\\.00').get(0).replaceAll(',','') : '';
```

The above code gives me a compile error:

> Save error: Illegal assignment from String to Integer

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Integer leadSize=(Integer.valueOf(email.plaintextbody.split('Base: ').size()) > 1) ? Integer.valueOf(email.plaintextbody.split('Base: ').get(1).split('\.00').get(0).replaceAll(',','')) : 0;
```